# Trying to have different costs for different time - Java

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to make my code make it so that it cost more for numbers above 7, It will cost 1 franc for every hour between 0 - 7 and 2 francs for times from 8 - 24. Right now I have this:

```
int start = user_input.nextInt();
int finish = user_input.nextInt();
int hours = finish - start;
int hours2 = finish - start;
int francs1 = 1 * hours;
int francs2 = 2 * hours;
if (start > 0 && finish < 7){
            System.out.println(hours + " hour(s) at a cost of " + francs1 + " francs");
        }else{
            if (start > 7 && finish < 24){
                System.out.println(hours2 + " hour(s) at a cost of " + francs2 + " francs");
            }else{
                if (start < 7 && finish > 7){
```

Start is the first value the user enters and finish is the second.

Comment: By the way, if you are actually working with time-of-day values, be aware of the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
int start = 8
int end = 10
int leftHandDiff = Math.min(7, end) - start
int rightHandDiff = end - Math.max(7, start)
int francs1 = (leftHandDiff > 0 ? leftHandDiff : 0) * 1
int francs2 = (rightHandDiff > 0 ? rightHandDiff : 0) * 2
```

Of course you must include your validations so that hours are not lower than 0 or bigger than 24, and that start is not after the end.

Comment: Yep i have the validations so that it cant be less than 0 or greater than 24, I'm trying to make it so that if someone enters for example, 4 and 12, it will add the 3 francs from 4 - 7 and the 8 francs from 8 - 12, displaying that the user owes 11 francs

Comment: My answer gives you that. Check it out

Comment: Have you thought about what should happen if start is 4 and end is 8? I mean 8th hour should count as 2 or 1? I think having 4-12 you should have like (4-7) * 1 + (12-7) * 2, otherwise you will loose time from 7th to 8th hour. Whatever you need, you can change constants in lines:
**int leftHandDiff = Math.min(7, end) - start** and **int rightHandDiff = end - Math.max(7, start)**

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was gonna sort out the 8 problem after